# apache override authentication in a specific folder

Tags: authentication, directory, apache-2.4, mod-auth

How do I change/override the authentication in apache to a different one in a subfolder?

I tried this one but it didn't work. How can I fix it?

```
<Directory "/">
    AuthName "Front End Access"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "xxxxxxx/.htpasswd_frontend"
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

<Directory "/backend/">
    AuthName "Back End Access"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "xxxxxxx/.htpasswd_backend"
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I have made a search, they showed up how to *disable* autentication, but I don't want to disable it: I want to change the AuthUserFile to a different one (and possibly change the AuthName)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your server's file system really have a top-level directory named `/backend`?

I suspect that what you need is to replace `<Directory /backend>` by either e.g. `<Directory /var/www/html/backend>` or `<Location /backend>`.  See [Configuration sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html).

Comment: deary me, i thought it was relative to apache's root directory :P thank you and shame on me